# How can I specify a regex pattern which matches only lines without a specific string?

Tags: regular-expressions

How can I specify a regex pattern which matches any line without

- `"lecture"` anywhere in it?
- `".pdf"` at the end?

Comment: With a true regular expression you cannot. What is it that you are really trying to do with such lines (or with the other, non-matching lines)? Tell us that and we can likely suggest how to accomplish what you want. (For example, if you just want to remove such lines then see commands `flush-ilnes` and `keep-lines`.) Typically, if you need the opposite of what a regexp matches you find what it matches and subtract that from the original search space to get the complement. But just what you're trying to do makes a difference in how you might want to proceed.

Comment: I want to remove lines without "lecture" anywhere in them. I want to remove lines without ".pdf" at the end of them. I was thinking of matching such lines and replace them with empty using `regex-replace`.

Comment: @phils WHen removing a line, not just remove the content of the line, but also the new line character at the end.

Comment: It's `M-x keep-lines` which you're wanting.  This lets you specify the pattern `lecture\|\.pdf$` for the lines you want to keep, and all non-matching lines are deleted.

Comment: @phils That last comment should be an answer instead.

Comment: The *stated question* isn't a duplicate, though (even though it precisely solves what turned out to be the actual problem).

Comment: FWIW, it *is* possible to do it with a true regular expression.  The problem is that this regexp is monstruous.   You can construct it by turning `.*lecture.*` into a DFA, then negating that DFA, and then turning that negated DFA back into a regexp.

Comment: @Stefan  In principle, what kinds of patterns are  not direct or easy  to be  represented in regex, and what are?

Answer (score 1):

For your *actual* problem, per the comments, <kbd>M-x</kbd> `keep-lines` is what you're looking for, and in your case you would keep lines matching the regexp `lecture\|\.pdf$`

---

As Drew comments, you can't do what you've actually asked for with a regular expression in Emacs, as PCRE-style arbitrary zero-width look-ahead assertions are not available.

If the pattern is anchored to the beginning of the string, then it becomes *practical* (but still not easy) to match "strings which do not start with X".  The following is a regexp which matches lines which do not start with `lecture` (and are not, in their entirety, a prefix of that word):

```
^\([^l]\|l[^e]\|le[^c]\|lec[^t]\|lect[^u]\|lectu[^r]\|lectur[^e]\).*
```

You get the idea.

In rare cases that's useful, but more often you would do what Drew outlined:

> Typically, if you need the opposite of what a regexp matches you find what it matches and subtract that from the original search space to get the complement.

---

You might also find this trick interesting:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `query-replace-regexp` and replace `.*` with:
`\,(if (string-match-p "lecture\\|\\.pdf$" \&) \& "")`

Note that this is matching and replacing *all* lines -- but the ones which match the embedded regexp are 'replaced' with identical text, and the ones which don't are replaced with an empty string.

Adding a newline <kbd>C-q</kbd><kbd>C-j</kbd> to the end of that `.*` search pattern would produce the same textual result as `keep-lines` with `lecture\|\.pdf$`

Comment: Thanks. In principle, what kinds of patterns are  not direct or easy  to be  represented in regex, and what are?

Comment: I'm not sufficiently familiar with the theory to be a good person to answer that properly.  Trying to use regexp to parse HTML or other arbitrary balanced forms is one [classic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454) mistake; and as already mentioned you can't have arbitrary zero-width look-ahead or look-behind assertions like PCRE provides, so you need to be consuming all the text that you're matching. I feel that the kinds of things you *can* match are indicated fairly well by the manual: `C-h i g (elisp)Syntax of Regexps`